# Laravel. Название маршрута к контроллеру ресурсов

Tags: laravel, laravel5

Изучаю фреймворк по урокам. Все маршруты приводить не буду, напишу те, с которыми проблема. В общем:

```
Route::resource('articles', 'ArticleController', [
    'parameters' => [
        'articles' => 'alias'
    ]
]);

Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function (){       
    Route::resource('articles', 'Admin\ArticlesController');
});
```

Вот в чём проблема:

```
+--------+---------------+-------------------------------+--------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
| Domain | Method        | URI                           | Name               | Action                                                                  | Middleware   |
+--------+---------------+-------------------------------+--------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
|        | POST          | admin/articles                | articles.store     | Corp\Http\Controllers\Admin\ArticlesController@store                    | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD      | admin/articles                | articles.index     | Corp\Http\Controllers\Admin\ArticlesController@index                    | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD      | admin/articles/create         | articles.create    | Corp\Http\Controllers\Admin\ArticlesController@create                   | web          |
|        | DELETE        | admin/articles/{article}      | articles.destroy   | Corp\Http\Controllers\Admin\ArticlesController@destroy                  | web          |
|        | PUT|PATCH     | admin/articles/{article}      | articles.update    | Corp\Http\Controllers\Admin\ArticlesController@update                   | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD      | admin/articles/{article}      | articles.show      | Corp\Http\Controllers\Admin\ArticlesController@show                     | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD      | admin/articles/{article}/edit | articles.edit      | Corp\Http\Controllers\Admin\ArticlesController@edit                     | web          |
|        | POST          | articles                      | articles.store     | Corp\Http\Controllers\ArticleController@store                           | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD      | articles                      | articles.index     | Corp\Http\Controllers\ArticleController@index                           | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD      | articles/cat/{cat_alias?}     | articlesCat        | Corp\Http\Controllers\ArticleController@index                           | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD      | articles/create               | articles.create    | Corp\Http\Controllers\ArticleController@create                          | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD      | articles/{alias}              | articles.show      | Corp\Http\Controllers\ArticleController@show                            | web          |
|        | PUT|PATCH     | articles/{alias}              | articles.update    | Corp\Http\Controllers\ArticleController@update                          | web          |
|        | DELETE        | articles/{alias}              | articles.destroy   | Corp\Http\Controllers\ArticleController@destroy                         | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD      | articles/{alias}/edit         | articles.edit      | Corp\Http\Controllers\ArticleController@edit                            | web          |
+--------+---------------+-------------------------------+--------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
```

Пути формируются верно, префикс "admin" учитывается для второго маршрута. Но имена маршрутов одинаковы. И это меня вводит в заблуждение. Я прохожу уроки на версии 5.5. Уроки же написаны на версии 5.2 и там имя ко второму маршруту, который с префиксом формируется таким образом: "admin.articles.index" и т.д. Прочёл документацию несколько раз и так и не понял что изменилось с версии 5.2 в именовании маршрутов к контроллерам ресурсов. Исходя из того, что при формировании имён не учитывается префикс, получается, что нужно для каждого метода своё имя задавать, чтобы оно не повторялось с уже имеющимся? Глупо это как-то и нелогично. Подскажите, может я где-то туплю? Уже второй день не могу разобраться в чём проблема :/

Answer (score 1):

Можно указать префикс для resource маршрутов:

```
Route::resource('articles', 'Admin\ArticlesController', [
    'as' => 'admin',
]);
```

Либо для всей группы *(нужна точка)*:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'as' => 'admin.'], function (){
    //
});
```